# State of Response object 'dead' while using livy with python

Tags: python, rest, cloudera, hue

I am trying to use livy, it is my first time with a REST api as well. Following the [tutorial](https://github.com/cloudera/livy), when I type

`r = requests.post(statements_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)`

and then

`r.json()`

I receive as ouput  `u'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session is in state dead'`. According to the tutorial, the session state should be iddle, but it seems to change to dead after is done with starting. I don't know what should I do to keep the state in `iddle` so I can make post request.

In the console where the server is running, I receive the following output `16/08/02 12:37:18 ERROR SessionServlet$: internal error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session is in state dead`

Comment: Without telling us what you've used for `statements_url`, `data` and `headers` it's hard to say. The docs actually say "Once the session has completed starting up, it transitions to the idle state:"

Comment: @doctorlove I am not using it locally, so let's say that `statements_url` is `http://myhost:8998/sessions/0/statements`, `data = {'code': '1 + 1'}`  and `headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` (the tutorial's value). If I go to http://myhost:8998/sessions I can see all the dead sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I realized that I am running spark with scala 2.11, and Livy only supports Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when I cancelled a snippet of code that was running in the Hue Notebook.

The only solution I found was to log out of Hue and then log back in.

(It would create a new session when you log back in)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same Issue and I got it resolved by creating the correct session type. i.e. while packaging Apache Livy my mvn got failed at python so instead of creating session for pyspark I created the session of spark and then my session was in idle state.